# How to make a class with a property of type "closure" codable?

Tags: swift, codable

If a class has a property of type "(Int,Int)->Int", is there any way to make it codable?

```
class ClosurePropertyForCodable: Codable{
    var handler: ((Int,Int)->Int)?
}
```

"static" ahead of "var" may silence the warning. Will static property not be encoded by default?

EDIT:

I have a handler-list for users to choose from. Each handler option corresponds to a certain math function. In future, I also want users to insert their custom math functions. So I add a "handler" property ((Int,Int)->Int) directly instead of an option number property(Int) to record the user's option.

Comment: Correct. Only properties belonging to the instance are encoded. But what do you actually *want* to do here? Do you want each instance of `ClosurePropertyForCodable` to have its own `handler`? And do you want `handler` to be encoded? If you do, *how* do you expect a closure, which represents *code*, to be encoded?

Comment: I indeed want each instance to have its own handler and to be encoded. Dose it mean no way to encode a closure property in fact?

Comment: Let's take a step back - what are you doing that requires you to encode a closure? You have an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Do you actually want to send this data somewhere or store it some where? Kind of puzzling since closures are usually used for programatic call backs, if you want to save values or transfer values you could store it in a struct and construct the closure later

Comment: I have a handler-list for users to choose from. Each handler option corresponds to a certain math function. In future, I also want users to insert their custom math functions. So I add  a "handler" property ((Int,Int)->Int) directly instead of an option number(Int) property to record the user's option.

Comment: @test1229 You should use a string or enum to model the various available options. Serializing arbitrary code is what Mach-O (macOS) and ELF (Linux) binary file formats are for. Serializing arbitrary code, shipping it across device boundaries, deserializing it on another device and running it is absolutely not what you would want to do, even if you could.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
typealias YourHandler = (_ a: Int,_ b: Int) -> Int

class ClosurePropertyForCodable: Codable {
    var handler: YourHandler?
    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. No case in enum can indeed silence the warning, but also ignore to encode the handler. In fact,  I want to encode the value of handler.